# Java construrctor with string params

Tags: java, constructor

How can I extract attributes values from the string parameter ?

```
public class Pays{
public Pays(String paysDescriptions) {
        //implementation
    }

}
pays= new Pays("p1:Europe:France, p2:Amerique:Canada");
```

**Edit:**

I gave an answer below to people who have never used this type of constructor (like me :p ) and who may need some explanations.

Comment: You are just confused with a comma in your string. It is a single string enclosed in one set of quotes, hence single param to your constructor.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? You're creating a new `Pays` Object with one String parameter `paysDescriptions ` = `"p1:Europe:France, p2:Amerique:Canada"`

Comment: @MadMatts thanks for your comment .. I can't understand how can I access to pays attributes..I have testCase and I should create the class implementation

Comment: @JunedAhsan yes I know it's only one string but I can't understand how I can manipulate it

Comment: Because they are other function which has as parameter for example : `p1` as `paysId` or `Europe` as `Country`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) API.

1. Break the parameter `paysDescriptions` using comma(`,`) as `regex`, then
2. Break the individual items using colon(`:`) as `regex`

**Example:**

```
public Pays(String paysDescriptions) {
    String[] split_1 = paysDescriptions.split(",");
    for (String split : split_1) {
        String[] split_2 = split.split(":");
        for (String sp : split_2) {
            System.out.println(sp); // use sp.trim() if spaces after comma
                                    // not required.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response it was exactly what I've done .. I used a HashMap .

Comment: I am glad that you found it useful. Please accept one answer so that question does not appear in open state.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstand the logic because it's the first time I saw this kind of conctructor..I have only the unit test class and I should implement the code for the source one. So I've used a `Map<String,String[]>` to split parameters and then I can access to the various attributes of my class.

```
Map<String, String[]> paysMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>(); 
    public Pays(String paysDescriptions) {

        String s = paysDescriptions;
        String[] pairs = s.split(",");
        for (int i=0;i<pairs.length;i++) {
            String pair = pairs[i];
            String[] keyValue = pair.split(":");
            paysMap.put(String.valueOf(keyValue[0]),new String[]  {String.valueOf(keyValue[1]), String.valueOf(keyValue[2])});

        }
    }
```